# Private repository in Git -- nothing pushed to Master branch

Tags: git, github

Greetings:  I am fairly new to GitHub but so far so good, until now.  I have a private repository and cannot seem to push my commits.  For example, I created a README.md file in my local directory.  When I run `git status` it shows that it is being tracked.  I can go ahead and add the file 'git add .', followed by `git commit -m "Create README.md"`.  When I run the status at this point, everything is good.  But, when I run a `git push`, I get a message:

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date
```

My local directory shows the README.md file, but nothing on the private repository.  I haven't any prior trouble with public repositories (i.e., creating new repositories and pushing commits), but can't figure out why this won't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must define your remote origin:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/first_app.git
```

Then your will be able to push to it:

```
git push origin master
```

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/

Comment: Thanks.  I cloned it using the GitHub app rather than using the command line.  I did it this time using the command line and your recommendation -- and it worked.  Thx.